# SQL Server Analytics and Reporting services in a remote location

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, archive, sql-server-2012

We have 3 separate environments: a production ,a staging and an archive/backup environment

A) Is it possible to have Analytics and Reporting services set up only on the archive environment? The archive environment would basically be a duplicate of the production, or is it critical that they operate on the environment that the original transaction happens? (Maybe the services need all exact logs etc?)

The point of this is to be able to "lighten" the critical system that is production, and move the burden to the archive where the services can consume more resources freely, without querying/disturbing the production environment.

B) Is there a reliable way to keep the archive/backup automated and reliable? We are looking into the [Redgate SQL](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-toolbelt/) tools, but any (preferably open source) suggestions or experience in this part would be invaluable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A) Yes, and this is a very common reporting or data warehousing configuration. You run your queries or build your data warehouse on a copy of production, in order to avoid impacting performance.

B) There are plenty of options supported by SQL Server itself: backup/restore, replication, log shipping. But you will need to look into the pros and cons of each one to find the best fit, e.g. how up to date do you need data to be on the reporting system?

Basically, you seem to be asking about implementing a reporting solution using a copy of a production database. As I mentioned, this is a very common scenario and you will find a lot of information on this site and elsewhere by Googling.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The process of archiving/backing up is the one that interests us most. Do you have any links to provide, or specific suggestions based on experience? I have done some research and I am a bit educated on the subject but I would like to know the common consensus on the best practices before I propose a method to my company.

Comment: @MihalisBagos You need to be more precise about what "archiving" means to you. For some people it means putting tapes into a fireproof safe offsite, for others it means just making backups, for others it's moving data to a reporting system etc. If you're mainly interested in backups then ServerFault and/or the DBA site would be a better place to ask.

Comment: its almost the same environment as production, meaning a duplicate SQL server database etc, with the added function of reporting services (and possibly analytics too in the near future). I am interested in what I describe in the oiginal question, run analytics and reporting on a duplicate environment so as to avoid server load (with the added benefit of data redundancy)